# Fill PDF form data from Excel with Adobe Acrobat Pro

Tags: c#, excel, adobe, vba

Is there any to fill PDF form fields using an Excel Data source? (Think 1000 pdf's)

For each row in Excel create a new blank pdf based from template "myForm.pdf" and fill in the matching values from the columns in Excel to the fields in "myForm.pdf" then save it as "myForm(i).pdf"

Finally Merge all the pdfs into a single PDF document.

VBA or Javascript for Adobe is fine as long as the concept holds true. Some manual parts are ok if it's not too much.

Not too many tutorials out there apparently so I really appreciate any expertise here.

Thanks!

Comment: Would vb.net code help? I don't have professional Adobe so I have never tried that in VBA but I am sure it is possible in VBA.

Comment: Build a vb.net application that takes a data set from excel and dumps it into a pdf? I rather see c# .net code because I don't actually know vb.net very well and wish not to convert it.

Comment: Ok Let me see if I can convert it to C#. Will post a code later today.

Comment: I have added the C# Tag as well so that you can get more responses :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As promised :)

**TRIED AND TESTED**

```
// Add reference to iTextSharp.dll. Freely available on the web. Free to use for non commercial applications.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using iTextSharp;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.xml;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Original Pdf
            string PDFFile = "C:\\MyOriginalPDF.pdf";

            // New Pdf
            string newPDFFile = "C:\\NewPDFFILE.pdf";

            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(PDFFile);
            PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(newPDFFile, FileMode.Create));

            AcroFields pdfFFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

            // Fill PDF Form Fields
            pdfFFields.SetField("FieldName1", "Value1");
            pdfFFields.SetField("FieldName2", "Value2");
            //
            // And So on

            // Use this to remove editting options by setting it to false
            // To keep editing option leave it as TRUE
            pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;

            // close the pdf
            pdfStamper.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**: To interact with Excel From C#, I would recommended visiting the below mentioned link.

**Topic**: VB.NET and Excel

**Link**: [VB.NET and Excel](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/interop/)

To convert the VB.Net Code to C# use the below link :)

**Topic**: Convert C# Code to VB.Net and vice-verse

**Link**: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools

Do let me know if you are still stuck and we will take it from there... :)

**More Edits!!!**

Inspired by your post, I finally ended up writing an article on my blog. Now all you have to do is copy the entire code and convert it into C# and make relevant changes to suit your needs :)

**Topic: Fill/Retrieve data from PDF Form Fields using VB.Net From an Excel File**

**Link**: http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/08/28/fillretrieve-data-from-pdf-form-fields-using-vb-net-from-an-excel-file/

Comment: Very cool library! Excellent work and very nice job on the blog. Well deserved 100 points. Thanks so much Siddharth.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was aiming Adobe Acrobat Pro, however we ended up using an alternative tool having the same problem.
In my company we use regularly [PDF Mail Merger](https://pdfmailmerger.com) for all types of PDF forms that we have to fill and send in bulk. We find it very easy to use.

## Usage:

You will be guided through 4 steps:

1. Upload PDF file
2. Upload Excel file
3. In the Editor you can drag'n'drop
   placeholders onto the PDF
4. Click to start the PDF filling process

### Advantages:

- Works with any kind of PDF file (doesn't require fillable form fields)
- Many spreadsheet formats supported (Microsoft Excel, Open Office Spreadsheet, CSV, TXT etc.)
- New PDF Form templates are set up very quickly
- PDF Form templates can be reused with one click
- No programming knowledge is required

### Disadvantages:

- If using the free plan, they will print watermarks on your PDF files

### Screenshots:

[Home Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJRDL.png)

[Upload PDF file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHiFk.png)

[Editor for drag'n'drop placeholders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5ijs.png)